# Noise Comparison in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compare, signals, noise

Assuming I have two signals (raw data as excel file) measured from two different power supplies, I want to compare the noise-levels of these signals to find out which one of them the noisier one. Both power supplies produce signals with the same frequency but the amount of data points are different. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: i don't know what the actual noise-free signal should look like. i only have the input and output (noisy signal).

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the [signal-to-noise ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) for each signal. This is just a ratio of the average signal power and average noise power, usually measured in decibels. An ideal noiseless signal would have SNR = infinity.

Recall that signal power is just the square of the signal amplitude, and to get the value `x` in decibels, we just take `10*log10(x)`.

```
SNR = 10*log10( mean(signal.^2)/mean(noise.^2) );
```

To separate the signal from the noise, you could run a low-pass filter over the noisy signal.

To get the noise you could just subtract the clean signal from the noisy signal.

```
noise = noisy_signal - signal;
```